# namespace duplicate issue in xml

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, xml-namespaces

I am encountering a namespace duplicate issue in the response xml of my webservice.
I have a responder.xsd that uses customer.xsd and common.xsd
My response xml is structured using the elements in these two xsds.
A sample XML response is as below:

```
...
<ns:RoleType></ns:RoleType>
<ns:Addresses>
  <ns:PostalInfo>
    <comm:AddressLine></comm:AddressLine>
    <comm:City></comm:City>
  </ns:PostalInfo>
</ns:Addresses>
<ns:ValidFlag></ns:ValidFlag>
...
```

where ns: is the customer namespace and comm: is the common namespace.

But the response that I get is as below

```
...
<ns1:RoleType xmlns:ns1="urn:Customer:domain:5"></ns1:RoleType>
<ns2:Addresses xmlns:ns2="urn:Customer:domain:5">
  <ns2:PostalInfo>
    <ns3:AddrLine xmlns:ns3="urn:Common:domain:5"></ns3:AddrLine>
    <ns4:City xmlns:ns4="urn:Common:domain:5"></ns4:City>
  </ns2:PostalInfo>
</ns2:Addresses>
<ns5:ValidFlag xmlns:ns3="urn:Customer:domain:5></ns5:ValidFlag>
...
```

Can someone help me understand why the same namespace is duplicating with incremental numbers like ns1,ns2 and comm1,comm2 etc?
How can I fix this?

Updated:
Code snippet that is well formed and with the root element.

```
<GetHCPResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:services:ServiceResponder:5" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:services:ServiceResponder:5 C:\Users\vijay\Desktop\wsdl\wsdl\Service_5_2\ServiceResponder.xsd">
        <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
        <StatusMessage>Success</StatusMessage>
        <HCP>
            <ns1:ID xmlns:ns1="urn:Customer:domain:5">29199486</ns1:ID>
            <ns2:CustomerClass xmlns:ns2="urn:Customer:domain:5">HCP</ns2:CustomerClass>
            <ns3:CustomerStatus xmlns:ns3="urn:Customer:domain:5">A</ns3:CustomerStatus>
            <ns4:RoleType xmlns:ns4="urn:Customer:domain:5">P</ns4:RoleType>
            <ns5:Addresses xmlns:ns5="urn:Customer:domain:5">
                <ns5:PostalContact>
                    <ns5:MasterAddressID>15863814</ns5:MasterAddressID>
                    <ns5:PostalInfo>
                        <ns6:AddressLine LineNo="1" xmlns:ns6="urn:CommonTypes:domain:5">8252 NW 25TH ST</ns6:AddressLine>
                        <ns7:City xmlns:ns7="urn:CommonTypes:domain:5">DORAL</ns7:City>
```

...

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: what webservice framework are you using?

Comment: Its a Java webservice

Comment: Is the real response well-formed?  Specifically, does it have a single root element?  (What you show lacks a single root and is therefore not well-formed.)  As I point out in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30945762/290085), namespace prefixes themselves are insignificant; it's the namespace URIs that matter.  You indicate that you're wondering why this is happening, but without showing us the code generating these responses, there's probably not enough information here to answer.

Comment: Sorry. I just pasted only the lines that had the namespace issue in my question above. My bad. Updated it with the code snippet, that is well formed.

Comment: The new XML you posted shows why all of the namespace prefixes have to be generated: Their parent elements are in the default namespace, and they are not.  Is that what you want?    We probably need to see your WSDL and XSD files to spot the issue, assuming the web service itself is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace prefixes matter only because of the namespace URI to which they're bound. The actual value of a namespace prefix is otherwise insignificant.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. But the problem is that we use datapower to externalized the webservice and Datapower has a limit of unique namespaces that it can allow. The limit is mostly within 10000. So for some responses that have multiple Address elements, the unique namespace becomes more than 10000. ex: ns:12252

Comment: Would it help if a simple XSLT transformation could consolidate the excessive namespace prefix declarations?

Comment: Yes it would help. But I would like to know what causes these excessive namespace declarations. I tried to create a sample Response XML using Altova XMLSPY and the response came out perfectly fine. It has only ns: and comm: namespaces and no excessive declarations. I wonder what causes the webservice alone to send the response with thousands of duplicate namespaces.

Comment: You'd have to ask the author of the web service or consult its source code.

Comment: Thanks Hughes. Do you feel it is a webservice issue and not an XSD problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are consuming a 3rd party web service and you dont want to modifiy the xsds and wsdls, right?

But as you said that its the same namespace...did you tried to update manually xsd and wsdl before consuming, unifying namespaces?

Comment: I am not using a 3rd part webservice. we build the webservice based on the schemas that I have mentioned and the XML code is the webservice response